# Ionic: fast loading images

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building a small app with Ionic 3 and angular 2/4

I have a problem to load a list of images from an URL (5MB per image)

It takes a lot of time to display my images.

How can I load images faster ?

There is any way to display images in low quality first ? (like Facebook and Whatsapp)

Any link, any tutorial, any blog ...

```
//js
private photo = "http://my-url.com";
private photo2 = "http://my-url-2.com";

//html
<div> <img [src]="photo"> </div>
<div> <img [src]="photo2"> </div>
```

Thank you !

Comment: You'll need to create smaller versions to serve up, then request the larger one when needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most convenient ways imho are:

1. compression - the first thing you need to ask yourself: Do I really need a 5mb image? Is it too big? Can it be compressed (e.g. jpeg/png)?
2. thumbnails - 1 (or more) version of the original image which are a lot smaller and therefore a lot faster to load. In many cases (e.g. list, overview) you don't even need the original image because the size of your img container is way smaller. So one way is to only load + display the size you need for that specific usecase. When you really need the 5mb version you could start with the thumbnail and replace it when the fullsize one is finished loading. This doesn't reduce the loading time, but feels way smoother.
3. preloading - you could preload the images (e.g. when you know they will be shown soon) to remove the slow loading part when your image is actually displayed.
4. caching - when your images don't change that much you might consider caching the images on your device. That way whenever you need to load a 5mb image for the second time (even after app restart) it takes the local copy instead of the remote one and can be shown almost instantly.

Ideally (and depending on your usecase) you combine all four things: Compressed images, different sized versions of your images, preloading when necessary and caching to make sure an image is only loaded once.

In my apps I'm using the simple but great plugin [ionic-image-loader](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader) which I can highly recommend. It's easy to implement and covers 3. and 4. with almost no effort.

I hope I could help!

Comment: Did this help you @NoteStylet ? Just curious

Comment: ionic-image-loader is not caching after app restarts. its loading from beginning. Can u please suggest me? What might the problem?

Comment: The plugin should Cache images even after restarting the app. Maybe check your config. The right place to look first is https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader/issues

Comment: I'm using capacitor with ionic and facing issues with this Cordova plugin any suggestions how to pre load images